# launch a variable from workspace windown in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, workspace

Say I have a variable in my workspace window as VAR_ABC.  At the end of my work (script/function), I want to launch this VAR_ABC in the variable editor window.

How can I do it?  It has more than 10 cols and so command prompt/disp etc are not useful.  Is there a way to `automatically launch` this variable without manually double clicking on the Workspace window?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [OPENVAR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/openvar.html):

```
openvar('VAR_ABC')
```